# IllegalStateException in MediaRecorder start method call

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

My app tries to record the sound by using the MediaRecorder API. My start recording method looks like this:

```
   public void start() {
      if(this.mRecorder == null) {
          try{

                 this.mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                 this.mRecorder.setAudioSource(1);
                 this.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(1);
                 this.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(1);
                 this.mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 
          } catch (RuntimeException re) {

          }

         try {
            this.mRecorder.prepare();
         } catch (IllegalStateException var3) {
            var3.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException var4) {
            var4.printStackTrace();
         }

         this.mRecorder.start();
         this.mEMA = 0.0D;
      }

   }
```

But I get crash reports from users on the following line:

```
 this.mRecorder.start();
```

The IllegalStateException  stack trace is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3493)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3533)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2791)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.mai(ZygoteInit.java:770)
Causedby:java.lang.IllegalStateException:
atandroid.media.MediaRecorder.start(NativeMethod)
atmeasure.sound.decibels.SoundMeter.start(SoundMeter.java:43)
atmeasure.sound.decibels.MyActivity.start(MyActivity.java:138)
atmeasure.sound.decibels.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:521)
atandroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1270)
atandroid.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6960)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3470)
```

The app is crashing for users. Any help!

Comment: `atmeasure.sound.decibels.SoundMeter.start(SoundMeter.java:43)` what is the exact line of `SoundMeter.java:43`?

Comment: Can you try to call `this.mRecorder.start();` inside the try after prepare? My guess would be the `prepare()` is throwing an exception that's being caught, thus you'd be calling start before the player is prepared

Comment: Make sure you have appropriate permissions defined in manifest.

Comment: Just looked into the docs, `prepare()` method throws an `IOException ` if the output file is not valid. And I'm not sure if `/dev/null` is a valid file? Which proves my first comment, so to fix it you'll need a valid file

Comment: @riadrifai  mine is a sound measurement app so i don't need to actually store the sound recording. i just need to measure the decibels in the sound so I am writing to /dev/null which is the null device where everything gets discarded. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device  do u have any code to fix this?

Comment: Do you know some of the devices it's crashing on or is it for everyone?

Comment: @riadrifai some popular devices have reported this issue which include Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 (mido), 3072MB RAM, Android 7.0
HTC One M9 (htc_himawhl), 3072MB RAM, Android 7.0
Sony Xperia XA1 Plus (G3412), 4096MB RAM, Android 7.0
Vivo vivo 1718 (1718), 4096MB RAM, Android 7.1
Sony Xperia Z5 Premium Dual (E6833), 3072MB RAM, Android 7.1
Motorola Moto E (4) Plus (nicklaus_fn), 2048MB RAM, Android 7.1
Motorola Moto G (5) Plus (potter_n), 2048MB RAM, Android 7.0
Lenovo VIBE K6 Note (K53b36), 3072MB RAM, Android 7.0

Comment: Hmm it seems they all have Android 7.0 and above. My advice would be keep it as is, and incase the `prepare();` crashed with an `IOException`, or if the android version is >= 7.0, create a temp file write to to and then delete it when done?